# Не отображается содержимое вкладки

Tags: html, css

Сделал вкладки на **html/css** по примеру. Вкладки работают только если содержат простой текст. Если вставить форму, то она вообще не отображается. В консоли код появляется

```css
 /* базовый контейнер табов */
    .tabs {
      min-width: 320px;
      max-width: 800px;
      padding: 0px;
      margin: 0 auto; 
    }
    /* стили секций с содержанием */
    section.tabs2 {
      display: none;
      padding: 15px;
      background: #fff;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
    .tabs input {
      display: none;
    }
    /* стили вкладок (табов) */
    .tabs label {
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 0 0 -1px;
      padding: 15px 25px;
      font-weight: 600;
      text-align: center;
      color: #aaa;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      background: #f1f1f1;
      border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
    }
    
    /* изменения стиля заголовков вкладок при наведении */
    .tabs label:hover {
      color: #888;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    /* стили для активной вкладки */
    .tabs input:checked + label {
      color: #555;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      border-top: 1px solid #009933;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
      background: #fff;
    }
    /* активация секций с помощью переключателя :checked */
    #tab1:checked ~ #content1,
    #tab2:checked ~ #content2,
    #tab3:checked ~ #content3,
    #tab4:checked ~ #content4 {
      display: block;
    }
    /* медиа запросы для различных типов носителей */ 
    @media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
      .tabs label {
        font-size: 0;
      }
      
      .tabs label:before {
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 18px;
      }
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
      .tabs label {
        padding: 15px;
      }
    }
```

```html
 <div class="tabs">
   <input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" checked>
   <label for="tab1" title="вкладка 1">Вход</label>
       
   <input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs">
      <label for="tab2" title="вкладка 2">Регистрация</label>
   <section class="tabs2" id="content1">
      <form id="modal-form">
      <div id="fields"> 
         <p><input name="email" placeholder="Email" id="contact-modal-form-imya"></p>
         <p><input name="password" placeholder="Password" id="contact-modal-form-phone" type="password"></p>
      <p><input type="submit" value="Войти" id="contact-modal-form-bttn"></p>
      </div>
      </form>
   </section>  
   <section class="tabs2" id="content2">
         <form id="modal-form">
      <div id="fields2"> 
      <p><input name="email" placeholder="Email" id="contact-modal-form-imya"></p>
      <p><input name="password" placeholder="Password" id="contact-modal-form-phone" type="password"></p>
      <p><input name="promo" placeholder="Промокод" id="contact-modal-form-imya"></p>
      <p><input type="submit" value="Регистрация" id="contact-modal-form-bttn"></p>
      </div>
         </form>
      </section> 
   </div>
```

Comment: `.tabs input {
  display: none;
}`  ??

Comment: @Igor, я тупица)или уже в глазах рябит)спасибо

Comment: Не за что. Успехов!